# Sonarqube, get back the original sonar way

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I'm using sonarqube and I've kind of messed up the rules inside the sonar way profile. Is there a way to put it back as it was before ? Like updating the java plugin. Because I don't find the list of rules inside the default "sonar way" profile on the sonarqube web site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the profiles page, there's a down-arrow next to the 'Create' menu at the top of the column on the left. It offers two options:

- Restore Profile - restore a single, specific profile from a backup file that you'll upload
- Restore Built-in Profiles - restore all default profiles for a single, specific language.

You want the latter.